# Custom DomainDataSource/Table view issue in RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

The project I'm using is based on a standard "Silverlight Business Application".

I have a number of tables which can display fine, but I'm looking to display a composite table based on SQL joins from other tables. So, in my Model.Designer.cs I have a small dummy class:

```
        public class JoinClass
    {
        [Key]
        public string LanguagesName { get; set; }
        public string VersionsName { get; set; }
        public string StringsName { get; set; }
        public string TranslatedStringsValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, in my DomainService.cs I create my query:

```
        public IQueryable<JoinClass> GetJoinClass()
    {
        IQueryable<JoinClass> query = from o in this.ObjectContext.TranslatedStrings
                                                                    where o.LanguagesID == 10
                                                                    select new JoinClass { LanguagesName = o.Languages.LanguagesName, VersionsName = o.Strings.Versions.VersionsName, StringsName = o.Strings.StringsName, TranslatedStringsValue = o.TranslatedStringsValue };

        return query;
    }
```

In the Silverlight app I access all this via a DomainDataSource:

```
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource Name="joinClass" LoadSize="20" QueryName="GetJoinClass" AutoLoad="True">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <ds:LanguageModelDomainContext />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
                <riaControls:SortDescriptor PropertyPath="LanguagesName"></riaControls:SortDescriptor>
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.SortDescriptors>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

and display the results in a DataGrid:

```
<sdk:DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Name="translatedStringsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=joinClass}">
```

nothing rocket science - the issue is that I can only get one record to display in the DataGrid. The query, GetJoinClass(), seems to execute fine and return nearly 600 records, but only one ever appears in the DataGrid. All the other standard queries I use don't have this problem.

Any pointers gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

Answer -

The `[Key]`. All properties of the class should have the `[Key]` attribute, not just one, e.g.

```
        public class JoinClass
    {
        [Key]
        public string LanguagesName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string VersionsName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string StringsName { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public string TranslatedStringsValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't know why.

Comment: When the data leaves the server, all data (despite its hierarchy) is flattened and stored in a "dictionary" where the index is the value of the `[Key]` property/properties. This reduces the amount of data that must be sent across the wire when one record exists as a child to many parents. Two "different" objects with the same key are seen as one immutable object based on the key. By adding the `[Key]` attribute to each of the members that make the record unique, you succeeded in defining how two different records are actually different.